# nslookup output shows result and error within a container

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, internal-dns, containers

```
/ $ nslookup aplha-sidecar.pa-beta.beta.cloud 
Server:         172.20.0.10
Address:        172.20.0.10:53

Name:   aplha-sidecar.pa-beta.beta.cloud 
Address: 10.151.62.118
Name:   aplha-sidecar.pa-beta.beta.cloud 
Address: 10.151.62.231

*** Can't find aplha-sidecar.pa-beta.beta.cloud : No answer
```

why nslook is showing both result(Address) and error "Can't find aplha-sidecar.pa-beta.beta.cloud "

Comment: apart from this i see  OS resolver was not appending the search strings for the DNS queries               cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 10.100.0.10
search svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5

Comment: I would suggest adding `-debug` so that you get to see the responses to all the different queries that `nslookup` decided to do. Maybe some strangeness for an `AAAA` lookup or some "search" attempt? `nslookup` is a weird and largely deprecated beast that provides terribly vague output by default...

Comment: What's in your /etc/resolv.conf ? can you add the contents to the question?